# How to add users to a FTP site in Windows 7's IIS?

Tags: windows-7, ftp, user-accounts, iis

I've setup a HTTPS and FTP site in IIS but how can I add users to use the FTP site?

Does they necessarily need an account with password in the computer to be able to use it?

Answer (score 4):

IIS's FTP system uses local or domain users for authentication.

Edited to add:  You can also [use IIS Manager users in IIS7+](http://www.iis.net/learn/publish/using-the-ftp-service/configure-ftp-with-iis-manager-authentication-in-iis-7) if you don't want to provide 'real' Windows users.

Comment: +1: You just add system users. Perhaps put them in a group that disallows them permission to logon to consoles and RDP, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can set up anonymous users in FTP for IIS.  Here is a [guide](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/26a80508-791c-42c2-bb2e-1427d4ddf8c2.mspx?mfr=true) for IIS v6, however there are guides on the internet for all version if you just google.